# Help! I can't share save files with my wife

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

I bought Skyrim VR a while ago, installed some mods (inluding Skyrim Script Extender) with the ModNexus Vortex tool. My wife created a character and played for a while, but our gaming PC was logged into my Steam account at the time. This meant that I could not play any Steam games even on another device while she was playing Skyrim.

Today, she tried to play Skyrim from her Steam account, but none of the save files were visible. This means she must either start again (which she does not want to do) or exclusively play on my Steam account, locking me out of most of my games. Here is what we have tried so far (and some useful case notes):

- we are sharing the PC this is running on, and we are also using the same Windows user profile. This means that the saves are stored in `[user profile]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim VR\Saves`
- we created a new save file from her steam account. It appeared in the above folder, but it is the only one visible from her Skyrim menu
- we already disabled Steam Cloud sync from BOTH our Steam accounts before trying anything
- because it's been modded with Vortex, we always launch the game from the Vortex client. We don't know where the Skyrim Script Extender executable is located. Launching Skyrim directly from Steam is not possible unless we disable the script extender
- Vortex has a profile management feature to segregate save files, but it was turned off.
- The save files are of a special type created by the script extender. The file names seem to depend on which Steam profile was active at the time. We tried renaming one of the files, but it didn't work. We really don't want "don't use mods" to be the answer here
- We tried turning Vortex profile management ON and using it's save file import feature, but this has not helped

We cannot tell which out of Steam, Skyrim, Vortex, or the Skyrim Script Extender is segregating our save files, nor can we find anything on the internet that tells us.

Everything that we can find on Google suggests that Skyrim (including VR) does NOT lock its save files to particular Steam accounts. The most likely culprit seams to be the Skyrim Script Extender, but Vortex may have a hand in it too. It seems really weird to me that modding tools would lock save files to particular accounts, but there seems to be demand for that, so it probably isn't malicious. There must be some way to turn it off, but I cannot work out how.

Comment: Why not start telling us what mod(s) you're using? If we can't know that, the answerer must speculate your problem, therefore cannot provide definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate question, +1. There are still some pertinent details we require, however. Both versions of Skyrim are the exact same? And what about SSE and the mods you're using?